# Eclipse dynamic web project not running on tomcat server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-7

I've installed a Tomcat server to my Eclipse (Kepler), so why does it need an internet connection when I run a dynamic web project?

Comment: What your are trying to achieve here?  Can you send error message or steps which you are following?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly - you need to start your tomcat server before you access your application. It's not related to internet connection.

**Overall Steps:**

1.Follow [THIS](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M4/tutorials/InstallTomcat.html) post answer steps to setup tomcat into eclipse

2.Add your application artifact (.war or .jar file) into tomcat server by right click on server ->  Add and Remove...

[image: Image 1]

3.Select your artifact and click on add button. You will see artifact moved from Available to Configured box.

[image]

4.Clean entire project (Project -> Clean)

5.Start you server and check console for any error.

[image]

6.If you don't see any error - access your application

Hope this helps!!